# Having an issue in Menu Tabs. And I am using carbonKit Framework

Tags: ios, swift, carbonkit

I want both tabs(Hello World, Tab) equal width of controller width . I put the complete code of my tabs. if anyone have suggestion for it. plz give suggestion.i am waiting. Comment & Answer Fast.

[image]

```
import UIKit
import CarbonKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, CarbonTabSwipeNavigationDelegate {

func generateImage(for view: UIView) -> UIImage? {
    defer {
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    }
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)
    if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
        view.layer.render(in: context)
        return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    }
    return nil
}

var iconWithTextImage: UIImage {
    let button = UIButton()
    let icon = UIImage(named: "home")
    button.setImage(icon, for: .normal)
    button.setTitle("Home", for: .normal)
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.blue, for: .normal)
    button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
    button.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 20, bottom: 0, right: 10)
    button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: -10, bottom: 0, right: 10)
    button.sizeToFit()
    return generateImage(for: button) ?? UIImage()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let tabSwipe = CarbonTabSwipeNavigation(items: ["HELLO WORLD", "Tab"], delegate: self)
    tabSwipe.setTabExtraWidth(40)
    tabSwipe.insert(intoRootViewController: self)

}

func carbonTabSwipeNavigation(_ carbonTabSwipeNavigation: CarbonTabSwipeNavigation, viewControllerAt index: UInt) -> UIViewController {
    guard let storyboard = storyboard else { return UIViewController() }
    if index == 0 {
        return storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FirstViewController")
    }
    return storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondTableViewController")
}

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This helps you.

First of all set `carbonSegmentControl` `frame` to Screen equal `Width` like this.

```
var frameRect: CGRect = (carbonTabSwipeNavigation.carbonSegmentedControl?.frame)!
frameRect.size.width = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
carbonTabSwipeNavigation.carbonSegmentedControl?.frame = frameRect
```

After that write this line for equal width.

```
carbonTabSwipeNavigation.carbonSegmentedControl?.apportionsSegmentWidthsByContent = false
```

**1. Before Equal Width**

[image]

**2. After Equal Width**

[image]

Comment: @veerendrapratapsingh, remove this line  `tabSwipe.setTabExtraWidth(40)` and after `tabSwipe.insert(intoRootViewController: self)` line add above 4 lines. `var frameRect: CGRect = (tabSwipe.carbonSegmentedControl?.frame)!
        frameRect.size.width = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
        tabSwipe.carbonSegmentedControl?.frame = frameRect
        tabSwipe.carbonSegmentedControl?.apportionsSegmentWidthsByContent = false`

Comment: Superb @Kuldeep, thanks for your answer. I wonder if the author of CarbonKit adds right to left tabs initiation for languages like arabic into the library.

Answer (score 0):

Before insert to root view controller:

```
carbonTabSwipeNavigation.carbonSegmentedControl.setWidth(view.frame.width / 2, forSegmentAt : 0)

carbonTabSwipeNavigation.carbonSegmentedControl.setWidth(view.frame.width / 2, forSegmentAt : 1)
```

This will set half of view width to each of the segments.